# Playing Videos in Android Browsers below Marshmallow (Jelly Bean, KitKat, Lollipop)

Tags: android, html, video

It's quite simple... I want this video to play in Android web browsers below Marshmallow (Lollipop, KitKat, Jelly Bean):

https://jsfiddle.net/zn9r0sLw/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <video poster="http://www.allkidscount.net/sponsors/videos/akc_trailer.jpg" width="500" height="281" controls preload="none">
      <source src="http://www.allkidscount.net/sponsors/videos/akc_trailer_small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your mobile device does not support this video.
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

My client wants the videos hosted on his server, he doesn't want them played through YouTube or Vimeo.

It works great on my Marshmallow tablet and phone, however, my client has a KitKat phone. I downloaded MEmu as an emulator for the other 3 devices since I do not physically posses any Android devices lower than 6.x.x, sure enough... none of the devices can play the video, either in the video tag or with the direct link to the video in the Browser URL.

I have double, triple, quadruple checked to make sure the MP4 is encoded correctly and by all accounts it is. I know YouTube videos can play on these browsers... so I'm obviously missing something. http://mobilehtml5.org/ says the video tag should work.

Comment: does that browser support HTML5 (needed for the `<video>` tag)? youTube is probably falling back to Flash

Comment: Yes... the poster shows up and then when you click play, it tries to play the video and then fails. However, the video plays just fine on a desktop browser, iOS and Android Marshmallow